# VS - Edit And Continue on Local IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis, edit, continue

I have hosted a webapp on my local IIS, using VS, but i'm unable to use option "Edit & Continue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Enable Edit & Continue on Local IIS

1. Open CMD with Admin Access (As Administrator)
2. Navigate to folder "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv"
3. Run Command "appcmd set apppool "DefaultAppPool" /+environmentVariables.add[@start,name='COMPLUS_ForceEnC',value='1']"

**You can change pool-name "DefaultAppPool" to which ever pool your locally hosted website/webapp is in.